# Wrong output in json file from Dictionary<string, int> C#

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I am trying to write a dictionary to json file from C#, but the output is wrong, here is my method

```
public static List<Dictionary<string, int>> CreateGlobalVectorAndRareVectors(List<Article> articleList)
        {
            List<Dictionary<string, int>> vectoriRari = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>();


            int i = 0;
            foreach (Article art in articleList)
            {
                
                Dictionary<string, int> aux = new Dictionary<string, int>();
                string[] title = art.Title1.Split(delimiterChars);
                string[] text = art.Text1.Split(delimiterChars);
                string[] completeText = title.Concat(text).ToArray();
                completeText = completeText.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();

                foreach (var word in completeText)
                {
                    if (!aux.ContainsKey(word))
                    {
                        aux.Add(word, 1);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        aux.TryGetValue(word, out int tempValue);
                        aux[word] = tempValue + 1;
                    }
                }
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aux);
                using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(@".\..\..\..\OutputData\" + art.FileNames[i] + ".json"))
                {
                    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                    serializer.Serialize(sw, json);
                }

                i++;

                vectoriRari.Add(aux);
            }


            return vectoriRari;
        }
```

Here is the output I want to get

```
{
    "USA": 1,
    "Microsoft": 1,
    "sees": 1
}
```

And this is the output I get

```
{
    \"USA\": 1,
    \"Microsoft\": 1,
    \"sees\": 1
}
```

The question is how do I get rid of \ ? I am using the Newtonsoft.Json library for formating the json files.

Comment: Are you sure you're not just seeing the Visual Studio debugger's representation of the string? Since you're using C#, it displays the string with the escape characters you would need to include to type that value as a string literal in your C# code. But those escape characters are not actually part of the string.

Comment: @AaronParrilla: That was my first thought as well, and then I saw that there was double serialization going on...

Comment: (If the OP is actually just saying what they're seeing in the debugger for the `json` variable, then yes, the escape characters aren't actually part of the string.)

Comment: If you want to demonstrate such a bug the code that's needed is `var dict=new Dictionary<string,int>(){ ["A"]=1,["B"]=2}; var json=JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);`. The rest is noise. If you can't reproduce the problem this way it means the rest of the code has a bug

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're serializing it twice:

```cs
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aux);
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(@".\..\..\..\OutputData\" + art.FileNames[i] + ".json"))
{
    JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
    serializer.Serialize(sw, json);
}
```

You've already got JSON from the first line - you're then encoding that JSON *as a JSON string* in the `Serialize` call later.

You can make this much simpler:

```cs
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(aux);
// TODO: Consider using Path.Combine instead
string path = @"..\..\..\OutputData\" + art.FileNames[i] + ".json";
File.WriteAllText(path, json);
```

Comment: This was the problem, thank you for pointing it out and thank you for the Path.Combine tip